# Add/Show Comments doesn't show existing comments, leaves them hidden

Tags: bug, comments

I've noticed this a few times lately, not sure if it's consistent or not. If I click the Add/Show Comments link, I get the box for typing in a new comment but the existing comments are still hidden.

Using Chrome Version 27.0.1453.93 m

Comment: Can you check the error log & see if anything interesting shows up there? I'm not seeing this.

Comment: @Shog9, when I brought up a new instance of Chrome with logging enabled it started working, but there's a huge delay between seeing the comment box open and the other comments unhidden.

Comment: There's an asynchronous request that fetches these comments. Maybe load up the dev tools in Chrome and watch the network tab? Then try the request manually & see what happens.

Comment: I agree with the network lag theory, I've seen comments take a while to load. Perhaps you notice it more because there are no loading dots like most of the async calls (@Shog9 maybe you should put the dots in when loading comments too).